# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

[Is there a perfect duty against gatekeeping?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108171/is-there-a-perfect-duty-against-gatekeeping)

Why was my question closed? In general, can we not rush to close question without reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The close banner says it requires "details or clarity".

Comment: i could say the same about your answer. but yeah, thanks for noticing my plight anyway